# Is it legal to assign a LiteralString as default value to a slot of type String in UML 2.5?

Tags: uml

I am not able to find out where the type of `LiteralString` is stated in the UML [2.5 specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF/).

In paragraph 7.5.2 the following diagram is given:

[image]

In paragraph 8.2.2 the following diagram is given:
[image]

In the description following paragraph 8.2.2 I cannot find any definition of the `type` attribute of any `Literal*`.

Since the multiplicity of Type is 0..1, I assume that none of the `Literal*` has type.

Is my assumption correct?

If my assumption is correct, then it is illegal to create a `slot` for an attribute of type `String` and assign a `LiteralString` as default value for this `slot`.

Comment: Late here, so... But your picture shows that `LiteralString` is a `LiteralSpecification`. So what do you miss?

Comment: From my understanding the attribute `type` of `LiteralSpecification` is not defined. The same for all of the other `Literal*`

Comment: You need to go down. Basically it's an `Element`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `type` is not specified in the documentation doesn't mean that the `type` attribute is empty.

While the type is not specified directly in specification, in 8.2.3 you can find

> 2 A LiteralString specifies a constant value of the PrimitiveType
>   String. Though a String is specified as a sequence of characters,
>   String values are considered to be primitive in UML, so their internal
>   structure is not specified as part of UML semantics.

Similar semantics is provided for all Literals.

It is allowed to assign LiteralString as a default value for a slot. Note that Literals are ValueSpecifications (each of the Literals is a LiteralSpecification which in turn is a ValueSpecification) and defaultValues always require instances of ValueSpecification as their value. See 9.4.2 and 9.5.2 for Parameter and Property defaultValue specification respectively.